# getDoc from firestore without searching for specific uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an issue getting the collection info. Using this code, I could only get the doc with a specific uid.

```
const snapShot = doc(db, 'Files', 'someUID');
const getSnapShot = await getDoc(snapShot);

console.log(getSnapShot.data());
```

I used this code to get all of the collection items but threw an error.

```
const snapShot = collection(db, 'Files');
const getSnapShot = await getDoc(snapShot);

console.log(getSnapShot.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data()));


Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'wc2', but it was: a custom gc2 object
```

**Q:** How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all documents from a collection or documents that match a query you should use `getDocs()` instead of `getDoc()` that is used to fetch a single document as the function name suggests.

```
const snapShot = collection(db, 'Files');
const getSnapShot = await getDocs(snapShot);

console.log(getSnapShot.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data()));
```